# Using Bluebird throws a compilation error in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, bluebird

I get an error

```
Bluebird<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Bluebird<boolean>
```

when compiling the following code

```
import * as Promise from 'bluebird'

function getPromise() : Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(true);
    })
}

let p : Promise<boolean> = getPromise();
p.then(a => console.log("Done"));
```

Bluebird version - 3.5.1

Node version - 6.10.3

Typescript version - 2.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue in newer versions of typescript, where the generic parameter of `new Promise` would be inferred by the expected return type. In 2.3 however you must explicitly specify the generic parameter to `Promise`:

```
function getPromise() : Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(true);
    })
}
```